# Is there a way to lower max number of threads on Elasticsearch cluster?

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I am running Elasticsearch as single node in EKS and it works fine. But when I try to launch a multiple nodes cluster of ES, I got an error:

```
[1]: max number of threads [1024] for user [elasticsearch] is too low, increase to at least [4096]
[2]: max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]
```

I know I should increase on host level before launch Elasticsearch, but I am using EKS Fargate which doesn't allow me to change host level configuration. So I am looking for a solution to make Elasticsearch cluster works in lower number of threads and virtual memory. I can create as many nodes as needed but each node has limited number of threads and memory. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Can't you just set the ulimit[1] when creating task definition on your template and set the value of Ulimit as it is requested by Elasticsearch.
[1] - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ecs-taskdefinition-containerdefinitions-ulimit.html

Comment: Here[1] is the update where the hard limit has been increased to 65535.
[1] - https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/1013#issuecomment-785327042

Comment: @JFC no there is no way to set it. The link you gave is ECS not EKS Fargate.